# Visual Studio doesn't seem to think it is compiling in 64 Bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit

So I'm trying to compile a project in Visual Studio 2010 and I seem to be running into problems compiling the code.

I have this chunk of code

```
#ifdef WIN_X64  
extern "C" int gainAndFindMax (int cnt,int gain,PSHORT pInput,PSHORT pOutput);
#else
extern "C" int __fastcall gainAndFindMax (int cnt,int gain,PSHORT pInput,PSHORT     pOutput);
 #endif
```

which is a pair of assembly functions written by a coworker.
 However, for some reason,  it keeps compiling toward the #else statement as if it is not compiling in 64 bit. 
I have all my project settings set to 64 bit and it should all be set up correctly however for some reason the
 " extern "C" int gainAndFindMax (int cnt,int gain,PSHORT pInput,PSHORT pOutput);" is grayed out it doesn't seem to compile.
Help would be much obliged

Comment: Are you defining `WIN_X64` yourself? Or are you looking for the `WIN64` preprocessor directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macros you should look at are `_WIN64` (or at least `_M_X64`), taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, `WIN_X64` is not a predefined symbol at 64 bit builds. Looking at the [list of predefined symbols in VS2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx), you should probably use `_M_AMD64` or `_M_X64` instead. There's also a `_WIN64` that will also be set on **all** 64-bit architectures, not just x64.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `_WIN64` or `_M_X64`